# DioError [DioErrorType.other]: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

i am using   dio: ^4.0.0
and  http: ^0.13.1
but when i try to upload media with a list of numbers it didnt work when i upload media without the list of numbers it worked perfectly

```
 authToken 14196
[   +6 ms] I/flutter ( 9404): *** Request ***
[        ] I/flutter ( 9404): uri: http://18.106.205.245:8080/api/media
[        ] I/flutter ( 9404): headers:
[        ] I/flutter ( 9404):  Authorization: Bearer 14196
[        ] I/flutter ( 9404):  content-type: application/json
[   +3 ms] I/flutter ( 9404): data:
[        ] I/flutter ( 9404): Instance of 'FormData'
[        ] I/flutter ( 9404): 
[  +46 ms] D/libc-netbsd( 9404): [getaddrinfo]: mtk hostname=18.106.205.245; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
[        ] D/libc-netbsd( 9404): [getaddrinfo]: mtk ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
[+4802 ms] I/flutter ( 9404): *** DioError ***:
[   +6 ms] I/flutter ( 9404): uri: http://18.106.205.245:8080/api/media
[   +7 ms] I/flutter ( 9404): DioError [DioErrorType.other]: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://18.106.205.245:8080/api/media
[        ] I/flutter ( 9404): #0      DioMixin.assureDioError (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:819:20)
[        ] I/flutter ( 9404): #1      DioMixin._dispatchRequest (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:678:13)
[        ] I/flutter ( 9404): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] I/flutter ( 9404): #2      DioMixin.fetch.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart)
[        ] I/flutter ( 9404): <asynchronous suspension>
[        ] I/flutter ( 9404):
```

Comment: No it didnt i already tried this

Comment: any update on this?